# Primitive types (string) as parameter- wcf method via ajax post doesn't work (works in fiddler)

Tags: ajax, wcf, primitive

Ok this one should be easy for someone who knows this sort of thing better.  I am going to limit the scope of the code I provide because this works in one variation (fiddler).

This problem is simple to explain: I have a method in WCF that takes a string as a parameter.  The method expects a request with a wrapped body style.  If I create a simple object in fiddler and send it over it works.  Something like {"submission":"something"}.  If I do this in via ajax in JSON it does not work.  I get a bad request error saying it is not allowed... this is cross domain but this is not the problem, I add the appropriate headers in the method to handle this.  In this case the method is never being called (it is like it is an issue with the signature).

Here is the thing though... if I make a really simple class with one property of a string and pass in an object it works fine.  Passing objects in a wrapped body style work fine.  Trying to do this with a "primitive type" such as a string does not... any ideas?

THIS DOES NOT WORK (but does work via fiddler)....

```
        var datain = new Object();
        datain.submission = "mysubmission";

        var dataToSend2 = JSON.stringify(datain);

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/Service/rest/Reflect",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: dataToSend2,
                        success: function (item) {
                            debugger;
                            alert(item);
                        },
                        error: function (xhr) {
                            debugger;
                            alert(xhr);
                        }
                    });
```

WITH THIS CONTRACT....

```
        [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "*", 
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    string Reflect(String submission);
```

THIS DOES WORK....

```
            var spec = new Object();
        spec.submission = "mysubmission";

        var dataToSend3 = '{"thespecial":' + JSON.stringify(spec) + '}';

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/Service/rest/Reflecting",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: dataToSend3,
            success: function (item) {
                debugger;
                alert(item);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                debugger;
                alert(xhr);
            }
        });
```

WITH THIS CONTRACT...

```
        [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "*",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    string Reflecting(Special thespecial);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can't send the primitive data types without wrapping in xml.

you can check the complete request structure after enabling the help in endpoint  behavior

suppose you have endpoint name "api" for  webHttpBinding then you can enable the help using following

```
    < webHttp helpEnabled = "true " />
```

After configuring it you can see the help as follow

```
  http://localhost:<port>/test.svc/api/help
```

This will show the actual request format.

Like to pass string  you can use the following format wrapper

```
  <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/ 
 Serialization/">Hello World</string>
```

or you can use stream input parameter

[Click](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-web.aspx)  here to implement streaming

Comment: Thanks for your response.  But this is not XML... this is a "POST" request using JSON.  I don't think much of what you say applies.